# Translate __toString

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this entity's __toString method:

```
/**
 * String
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    // I Have:
    // (EMR132 - Escuela Superior Mariano Moreno) Primary - 3 Bº Degree - Afternoon Shift
    // I Want:
    // (EMR132 - Escuela Superior Mariano Moreno) Primario - 3er Grado Bº - Turno tarde

    $levels = array(
        'primary' => 'Degree',
        'secondary' => 'Year',
    );

    return sprintf("(%s) %s - %s %sº %s - %s Shift", // Translate Format
            $this->school, 
            ucfirst($this->level), // Translate (fixed values)
            $this->degree, 
            $this->division, 
            $levels[$this->level], // Translate (fixed values)
            ucfirst($this->shift)  // Translate (fixed values)
    );
}
```

I need translate the string INSIDE the method.
But is not possible get a service (translator) inside a entity.

How to create translatable __toString methods?

Answer (score 0):

Translation is an issue for the view layer. I would encourage you to just output English from the `__toString()` method, then get its translation when you display it (i.e. in the view layer/templating).